# How to split overlapping values from different axis?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, labeling, ticks

There are overlapping numbers in the plot below (the left down corner). The axis $T_e$ has the value $10^{0}$, and the axis $n_i$ has $10^9$. But the problem is that the values are imaged in the same place, so it seems like the $n_i$ and $T_e$ axis have the number $10^8$.

[image: Overlapping]

Moreover, the turned plot doesn't have the problem, the values are splitted:

[image]

But it looks worse overall. I need to split the numbers without turning the plot.

Comment: does adding the option  `PlotRangePadding ->Scaled[.05]`  (or some other value instead of .05) help?

Comment: @kglr, it works, thank you very much! Didn't know about this option. You can post your answer and also use a [result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmvLb.png). I choosed `Scaled[.06]` and slightly increased plotting diapason of the planes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Olexot's comment, adding the option `PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.06]` (or an appropriate value instead of .06) solves the issue:

[image]